# How does boostrap alert dismiss work?

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

[Here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/components/#alerts-dismissible) is example about bootstrap dismiss:

```
<div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible" role="alert">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
    <strong>Warning!</strong> Better check yourself, you're not looking too good.
</div>
```

I do not undestand how javascript handler which attached to `button` determines what `div` elemnt to close.  What if there are several `div` elements with `class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible"` and `role="alert"` - how framework detects right element to hide?

**P.S.** Will it stable work if `role="alert"` removed?

Comment: It uses the magic of `this` to determine which one performed the action and exclude the others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The button is inside the alert element and event listeners can easily isolate the element an event occurred on and traverse from that element to it's parent(s) , siblings etc

Simplified example without framework:

```js
$('.alert .myButton').click(function() {
  // "this" is instance of myButton event occured on
  $(this).closest('div.alert').hide()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="alert">
  Content 1 <button class="myButton">Hide Content 1</button>
</div>

<div class="alert">
  Content 2 <button class="myButton">Hide Content 2</button>
</div>
```